# I have problems implementing the css and js animation files in my django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, codepen

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = '@6qt%i+0&_=z0#zl^+!u3bw6c7dmg4e3khboj%7s7439z9#ky('
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hap.apps.HapConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hookaparty.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hookaparty.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>hookaparty</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/hap.css'%}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'js/hap.js' %}">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:gray;">
    <nav class="nav">
  <a href="#" class="nav-item is-active" active-color="orange">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-item" active-color="green">About</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-item" active-color="blue">Testimonials</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-item" active-color="red">Blog</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-item" active-color="rebeccapurple">Contact</a>
  <span class="nav-indicator"></span>
</nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have posted a link to how i have arranged my files as well:
[This is how i have placed my files:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFJrA.png)

I'm having this problem since a really long time and im not being able to implement any animations from codepen, please provide help regarding this.
Any help would be really appreciated, looking forward to the solution.

Comment: your static files are wrongly placed bring them one directory back (same as templates directory) (out of hap directory)

Answer (score -1):

Try running this command first,

`django-admin collectstatic`

Here is [official](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) doc. for collect static.